Browser extensions: How do developers test/live code their JS for a third party website/SPA?
My question is about browser extensions written with javascript.
Tutorials for writing a browser extension always seem to use some minimal boilerplate HTML/CSS/JS as the test site (index.html = "Hello World").
So how do developers write browser extensions that target third party websites (i.e. YouTube, Twitch)?
How do they test their code without access to the website's server? Do they perform all testing on the site live and just use dev tools and keep refreshing the site manually?
If not, what is used to "live code" with javascript in this scenario? How would a developer write a browser extension and test that it works without having access to the website's source code?

If the extension depends on DOM structure of the page which can change unpredictably, you'll have to test on the live site e.g. using puppeteer.

@woxxom Oh cool, I've used puppeteer via python but not on its own. Do you know of a link that would explain how to set up this kind of environment? I use VSCodium. I don't know that much about javascript, and I am much more familiar with python.

Puppeteer uses CDP. There are many CDP clients for python. I don't know which one is better.

Cool thanks so much

@woxxom Hi if you want please make your comment an answer and I will select it as the correct answer.
